# Defining a Stack reference variable

Tags: java, stack

I am having a problem while making an instance of my stack in the class GameController.java:

```
import java.awt.*;

public class GameController implements ActionListener {

private GameModel model;
private MyStack<DotInfo[][]> dots;
private int size;

/**
 * Constructor used for initializing the controller. It creates the game's view 
 * and the game's model instances
 * 
 * @param size
 *            the size of the board on which the game will be played
 */
public GameController(int size) {
    this.size = size;
    model = new GameModel(size);
    dots = (MyStack<DotInfo[][]>) new DotInfo[size][size];
}

/**
 * resets the game
 */
public void reset(){
    model.reset();
}

/**
 * Callback used when the user clicks a button (reset or quit)
 *
 * @param e
 *            the ActionEvent
 */

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

}

/**
 * <b>selectColor</b> is the method called when the user selects a new color.
 * If that color is not the currently selected one, then it applies the logic
 * of the game to capture possible locations. It then checks if the game
 * is finished, and if so, congratulates the player, showing the number of
 * moves, and gives two options: start a new game, or exit
 * @param color
 *            the newly selected color
 */
public void selectColor(int color){
    Stack<DotInfo[][]> newStack = new DotInfo[size][size];
    for (int i=0;i<size;i++) {
        for (int j=0;j<size;j++) {
            if (model.dots[i][j].isCaptured()) {
                dots.push(dots[i][j]);
            }
        }
    }
    while (model.getCurrentSelectedColor()!=color) {
        color=model.setCurrentSelectedColor(color);
        //for (int i=0;i<)
    }
}
}
```

This is my Stack.java class:

```
public class MyStack<T> implements Stack<T> {

private T[][] array;
private int size;

public MyStack(int size) {
    this.size = size;
    array = (T[][])new Object[size][size];
}

public boolean isEmpty() {
    return size==0;
}

public T peek() {
    return array[size][size];
}

public T pop() {
    T popped = null;
    popped = array[size][size];
    size--;
    return popped;
}

public void push(T element) {
    size++;
    array[size][size]=element;
}
}
```

I was also wondering whether I defined my stack class in the right way? A little help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does your code compile?  Since `dots` is defined as a Stack where each element is a two-dimensional array of DotInfo objects, your initializing of `dots` in the constructor should be something like `dots = new MyStack<>();` in Java 8 and `dots = new MyStack<DotInfo [][]>();` in older Java implementations.

Answer (score 0):

The stack does not work properly because you need to set internal position field to 0 in constructor, not to argument `size`.

Also [size][size] is useless, its always the diagonal in your stacked objects, just use [size] (1 dimensional array) for a stack, below is a working stack of type T:

```
public class MyStack<T> implements Stack<T> {

private Object[] array;
private int size, int position;

public MyStack(int size) {
    this.size = size;
    position = 0;
    array = new Object[size];
}

public boolean isEmpty() {
    return position < 1;
}

public T peek() {
    if (isEmpty())
        throw new RuntimeException("Stack is empty");

    return (T)array[position];
}

public T pop() {
    if (isEmpty())
        throw new RuntimeException("Stack is empty");

    return array[position--];
}

public void push(T element) {
    if (position >= size - 1)
        throw new RuntimeException("Stack is full");

    array[++position]=element;
}

}
```

Also, for the board game you make why use a stack at all, just use a 2 dimensional array like:

```
public class Dot {
    //whatever information you need about a dot here

    //As example just say Hello
    public void sayHello() {
        System.out.println("Hello");
    }
}
```

And use it as 2D-Array:

```
//this are chess board dimensions (8 x 8)
public static final int SIZE_X = 8;
public static final int SIZE_Y = 8;

//create the board, made of Dot instances
Dot[][] board = new Dot[SIZE_X][SIZE_Y];
```

To find and use a given Dot:

```
//get reference of dot at position x, y
Dot dot = board[x][y];

//check if it exists, and if it does, make it sayHello()
if (dot != null) {
    dot.sayHello();
}
```

Comment: I have to use a stack array its for an assignment

Comment: How would i then initialize my stack in my GameController.java class

Comment: just use stackArr = new MyStack[size];

Comment: MyStack[ ] stackArr

Comment: What is the game, exactly?